# Convert Loopback 4 filter to SQL where clause

Tags: sql-server, typescript, loopback4

In loopback 4 the filter object received by Get, Count, ... looks like:

```
{
  where: {
    property: {
      op: value;
    }
  }
}
```

I like to convert this to SQL where clause and use it on my repository layer to build my select statement. Is this possible? and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible at the moment. This feature request is being tracked by [#4757](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/4757).

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be related to what I'm asking! I need to get the filter object converted to TSQL however the ticket is about definition changes!

Comment: The issue was spun from a migration perspective but the crux of the problem that it's trying to solve is the same - How to intercept and dump the raw database commands from the respective connectors. Hence solving #4757 would require solving this issue as a prerequisite.